# How do I average two points in python in OpenCV?

Tags: python, syntax, opencv

I have been trying to figure out how to average 2 points in OpenCV but whenever I try something, I usually get an error involving incorrect use of tuples. I am trying to find the center point of the lines returned by cv.HoughLines2. I know that line[0] stores the (x1, y1) and line[1] stores (x2, y2) term but I do not know how to average such that I can use them in cv2.circle().

How do I average two points in OpenCV?

```
lines = cv.HoughLines2(dst, storage, cv.CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC, rho, cv.CV_PI/(theta+1), thresh_1, min_len, max_dist)

i = 0
avr = 0
for line in lines:
         #print line

        cv.Line(image, line[0], line[1], cv.CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 1, 8)
        i = i+1
        avr = (line[0] + line [1])/2

        cv2.circle(image, avr, 4, cv.CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You average the x, and the y, seperately and recombine into a tuple.

I forget python syntax, so the psuedocode would be:

```
avg=[ (point1_x+point2_x)/2, (point1_y+point2_y)/2 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding tuples in Python seems to concatenate them:

```
In [1]: (1, 2) + (2, 1)
Out[1]: (1, 2, 2, 1)
```

This is not what you want. Try:

```
avr = ((line[0][0] + line[1][0])/2, (line[0][1] + line[1][1])/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
avr = cv.cvPoint((line[0].x + line [1].x)/2, (line[0].y + line [1].y)/2)
```